# How often has a major league team hit only a home run and a triple in a single game?

Tags: baseball, history, statistics

On June 26, 2015, the Mets had two hits, a home run (Granderon) and a triple (Hererra), but no singles or doubles, and they won the game (2-1 over the Reds).

Did the Mets pull off a baseball first? Has any other major league team hit only a home run and a triple in a single game, and if so did they win?

Answer (score 3):

There are 16 occasions listed in Baseball Reference's play index where a team has had exactly two hits, with one triple and one home run. Surprisingly, that team has won 7 of the 16 games, including the Mets most recently. The previous occurrence was [July 27, 2013](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/LAN/LAN201307270.shtml), when the Reds lost to the Dodgers. The last team to win with only a triple and HR was the Diamondbacks over the Cubs on [July 21, 2008](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI200807210.shtml).